# How to connect to a protected Sqlite3 database with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, zip, db-browser-sqlite

I created a `SQLite3` database and protected it with a password ("test") thanks to the application `DB browser for SQLite`.
In order to connect to my database via `Python`, I need to provide the password but I can't figure out how to do that. I tried the following code:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db", Password="test")
cur=conn.cursor()
```

**EDIT:**

My `SQLite3` database has been encrypted with `SQLCipher` (see image).
[image]
If I run the following code:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
```

I get this error:

```
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

How can I pass the password in order to connect with my `db` via Python?

**EDIT 2**

Here a brief summary of what I try to achieve. I am developing an application with `Python 3` requiring a pre-populated database but this database needs to be protected with a password.
After extensive research, it seems complicated to connect an encrypted `SQLite3` database via `Python 3`. A library calls `pysqlcipher` exists but only for Python 2.7. My next question will be maybe too broadly and I apology in advance. Is there another portable database that exists allowing me to protect it with a password and still get access to Python?
Another idea that I have in mind in order to troubleshoot my problem is to use the `zipfile` library. This [link](https://www.sqlite.org/zipfile.html) mentions that the `zipfile` module does not support encryption but it’s not clear if encryption refers to the `SQLite3` database or to the zip file. The idea would be to zip my unprotected `DB` into a protected zip file as it seems I can do that ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.setpassword)).
The goal of this edit is to get new ideas on how to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Try Jonathan's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964763/using-sqlcipher-in-python-the-easy-way
Worked for me

Answer (score 5):

If your database is encrypted with SqlCipher, you need to install sqlcipher in your SO
Windows: [Download](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/verify/4.0.0/sqlcipher-v4.0.0.zip)

Linux: `sudo pacman -S sqlcipher` or

```
sudo apt-get install sqlcipher
```

After you need the pysqlcipher3 lib: `pip install pysqlcipher3`

See: https://github.com/rigglemania/pysqlcipher3

my sample code is:

```
from pysqlcipher3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3


class Database(object):
    def __init__(self, dbname):
        self.dbname = dbname

    def connDB(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbname)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("PRAGMA key='mypassword'")

    def createDB(self):
        self.connDB()
        self.cursor.execute(
            '''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name TEXT NOT NULL,
            login TEXT NOT NULL,
            passwd TEXT);
            '''
        )

        self.cursor.execute(
            '''
            INSERT INTO users (name, login, passwd)
            VALUES ("Admininstrator", "admin", "12345")
            '''
        )
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

    def queryDB(self, sql):
        self.connDB()
        self.cursor.execute(sql)

        if sql[0:6].lower() == 'select':
            result = self.cursor.fetchall()
            self.conn.close()
            return result
        else:
            self.conn.commit()
            self.conn.close()
```

Comment: Hello freind. I have a problem, I tried to install in linux apt-get install sqlcipher worked ok, so when I try to install using pip install pysqlcipher3 I got error. In other hand, I tried downloading from your windows version link. But I'm not sure how to do that. Please could you explain to me how to install in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

You need the [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) module to read that database. The default SQLite3 module has no support for that. See https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Encrypted-Databases

Comment: What do you mean by `SQLCipher` module? Are you talking about the `pysqlcipher`?