# translating SQLcipher GUI to CLI (or pyhton)

Tags: python, sql, encryption, sqlcipher

The question is simple

**How can i turn this**
[SQLciper GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6xyV.png)

Into lines of code either in SQLciper CLI or using a python module ?

**Here's what i've tried (FAILED ATTEMPTS)**

attempt on python using a module

```
c.execute("PRAGMA key='something'") 
c.execute("PRAGMA kdf_iter = 1")
c.execute("PRAGMA kdf_algorithm = PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1")
c.execute("PRAGMA hmac_algorithm = HMAC_SHA1")
c.execute('SELECT type,name,sql,tbl_name FROM "main".sqlite_master')
```

attempt on SQLcipher CLI

```
sqlite> PRAGMA key='secretkeyhere';
sqlite> PRAGMA kdf_iter = 1;
sqlite> PRAGMA cipher_hmac_algorithm = HMAC_SHA1;
sqlite> PRAGMA cipher_kdf_algorithm = PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1;
sqlite> .tables
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

It always returns this error, Please help me :")

```
pysqlcipher3.dbapi2.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

Comment: see of this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964763/using-sqlcipher-in-python-the-easy-way

Comment: All of the API documents are here: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/